# TDS Project Build Error in Azure DevOps CI

Tags: tds

I am getting below error while trying to Build my TDS project - Common.Website.TDS using msbuild task in Azure DevOps CI -

```
packages\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.5.8.0.6\build\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.targets(681,5): Error MSB4044: The "BuildItemWebDeployFiles" task was not given a value for the required parameter "SolutionConfig".
Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'
```

Please suggest how to resolve this error.

Comment: How do you execute script PublishWebDeploy.ps1? What are parameters?

Comment: Hi @Peter, we are getting this error in the msbuild task of Azure devops CI pipeline.    We are far from executing the ps1 script which will be part of Azure devops CD task.

Comment: Hi @NewbieHere Can you describe more in detail your CI Pipeline within your question? This will help somebody to identify their problem in the future

Answer (score 4):

The error got resolved by adding parameters - 
/p:SolutionConfig = packages.config file with full path